# perl list subs in a package, excluding imported subs from other packages

Tags: perl, package, subroutine

There's several way to list all subs in a package:

```
sub list_methods {
    my $package = shift;
    no strict 'refs';
    return grep { defined &{"$package\::$_"} } keys %{"$package\::"}
}
```

But, if the package 'use' other packages such as 'File::Basename', the subs like 'fileparse' will be listed as well.
I tried to 'require' packages instead of 'use' them, the problem can be resolved. On the other hand, if I 'require' packages, I have to specify the full path of the subs.

Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

```
use B qw( svref_2object );

sub list_nonimported_subs {
    my ($pkg_name) = @_;
    my $pkg = do { no strict 'refs'; *{ $pkg_name . '::' } };

    my @nonimported_subs;
    for my $name (keys %$pkg) {
       my $glob = $pkg->{$name};
       my $code = *$glob{CODE}
          or next;

       my $cv = svref_2object($code);
       my $orig_pkg_name = $cv->GV->STASH->NAME;
       next if $orig_pkg_name ne $pkg_name;

       push @nonimported_subs, $name;
    }

    return @nonimported_subs;
}
```

There's a flag that will tell whether the CV in a glob is imported or not, but I can't find how to get that using B, so I check the `__PACKAGE__` of the sub against the package being inspected.

It's impossible to tell whether something is a method or not, so I generalised the name of the sub.

Comment: (Phew! that took me a 45 minutes!)

Answer (score 3):

PPI will parse the source, so the module doesn't even need to be loaded:

```
use PPI;

my $source = $INC{'Some/Module.pm'};  # or whatever
my $Document = PPI::Document->new($source) or die "oops";
for my $sub ( @{ $Document->find('PPI::Statement::Sub') || [] } ) {
    unless ( $sub->forward ) {
        print $sub->name, "\n";
    }
}
```